# Jackon API with aggregate objects for conversion from JSON to a Class

Tags: java, json, oop, selenium-webdriver, jackson

How to convert the Json to class using jackson api if we have the following two classes
Class1 and class 2:

```
public class NestedPOJO {
    

    String firstname;
        Integer age;
        Details detail;
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public Details getDetail() {
            return detail;
        }
        public void setDetail(Details detail) {
            this.detail = detail;
        }
}

    public class Details {
        String firstname;
        String lastname;
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
            
    }
```

Here is the Jackson API code, that I used:

```
    NestedPOJO n = new NestedPOJO();
   ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    n = m.readValue(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\payload - Copy.json"), NestedPOJO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
NestedPOJO nestedPOJO = mapper.readValue(loadDataAsString("payload - Copy.json"),NestedPOJO.class);
```

and call the below method as loadDataAsString

```
/**
 * This method will help to load data from the respective JSON file.
 * @param dataRequestType String
 * @return String
 */
protected String loadDataAsString(String dataRequestType) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource(dataRequestType)).getFile());
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //logger.error("Exception occurred during load data for {}", dataRequestType, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This approach will definitely work for you. If you got any issue regarding path then correct it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks but the path i used is correct and is able to load the json.The issue occurs with the aggregate object.

Comment: Add your JSON file. Explain accordingly to JSON about your needed outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your classes and code, and it works fine.  Maybe your JSON is not correct.  Here is what I used:  {"firstname":"fn","age":10,"detail":{"firstname":"fn","lastname":"ln"}}